# SetWindowsHookEx in a node.js module using node-nan

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I'm trying to create an Electron node.js application that can perform certain functions using global keybindings. The global keybindings API in Electron doesn't work in games unfortunately so I need to create a native node module that listens to these low level key events.

So i'm using node-gyp to compile the project with visual studio 2015 and nan to provide the communication between node and c++. I've managed to get both aspects of the project working seperately(the low level key bindings and the node.js<-->nan communication) but I'm having trouble combining them. I also admit I have very little experience with c++(I haven't written a single c++ program).

```
#include "node_modules/nan/nan.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Nan;

HHOOK _hook;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

class KeyboardEventWorker : public AsyncProgressWorker {
 public:
  KeyboardEventWorker(Callback *callback, Callback *progress)
    : AsyncProgressWorker(callback), progress(progress) {}
  ~KeyboardEventWorker() {}
  
  LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {  
    executionProgress->Send(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(nCode), sizeof(nCode));
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  }
  
  void Execute (const AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress& progress) {
    executionProgress = &progress; //PROBLEM #1
        _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, HookCallback, NULL, 0); //PROBLEM #2
    
    SleepEx(INFINITE, true);
  }


  void HandleProgressCallback(const char *data, size_t size) {
    HandleScope scope;
    
    v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[] = {
        New<v8::Integer>(*reinterpret_cast<int*>(const_cast<char*>(data)))
    };
    progress->Call(1, argv);
  }
  
  private:
    Callback *progress;
    AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress *executionProgress;
};

NAN_METHOD(DoProgress) {
  Callback *progress = new Callback(info[0].As<v8::Function>());
  Callback *callback = new Callback(info[1].As<v8::Function>());
  AsyncQueueWorker(new KeyboardEventWorker(callback, progress));
}

NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init) {
  Set(target
    , New<v8::String>("init").ToLocalChecked()
    , New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(DoProgress)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(asyncprogressworker, Init)
```

Problem #1: To be able to send back messages to node.js, I'l need to copy the pointer of AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress and make it available to the entire class so when HookCallback triggers it can send a message to node.js.

The compiler doesn't like this

> ..\binding.cc(21): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const
> Nan::AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress *' to 'Nan:
> :AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress *'
> [C:\Users\eksrow\gdrive\projects\vscode\node-native-hello-world\build\bindin
> g.vcxproj].
>
> ..\binding.cc(21): note: Conversion loses qualifiers

Formatted:

> 'const Nan::AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress *'
>
> 'Nan::AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress *'

This one I managed to solve by adding the keyword const to private member *executionProgress;. But I don't understand why that would fix it, const variables aren't supposed to be changed once they are set. Why does this compile?

Problem #2: This one is very peculiar:

> ..\binding.cc(22): error C3867: 'KeyboardEventWorker::HookCallback':
> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer t o member
> [C:\Users\eksrow\gdrive\projects\vscode\node-native-hello-world\build\binding.vcxproj]

I've looked up many examples online and they all have the same syntax regarding this:

1. [SetWindowsHookEx #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180773/setwindowshookex-for-wh-mouse?lq=1)
2. [SetWindowsHookEx #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22267909/530543)

I can't see the difference between my code and theirs regarding that line.

If I do what the compiler says and add an ampersand to that line, it gives a completely different error:

> ..\binding.cc(22): error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member
> function expression [C:\Users\eksrow\gdrive\proj
> ects\vscode\node-native-hello-world\build\binding.vcxproj]
> ..\binding.cc(22): error C2660: 'SetWindowsHookExA': function does not
> take 3 arguments [C:\Users\eksrow\gdrive\project
> s\vscode\node-native-hello-world\build\binding.vcxproj]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Problem #1**, you correctly identified the `const` qualifier as the problem.

The reason you can assign to the `const` member variable after declaring it is because of the placement of `const` in `const AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress *executionProgress`. This is a variable pointer to a constant AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress. This means you can change the pointer's value (for instance, re-assign it as in your example above), but you cannot change the data it points to. [The top answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const) has a very good explanation of this concept.

**For problem #2**, the error is caused by trying to pass a member function of your class as a function callback. This is simply not possible (well, without a workaround...see below) - a member method is not the same as a function, which is what `SetWindowsHookEx` is expecting. You could make your callback function `static`, but then would not be able to access the `_hook` member.

[Here is an external page](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/assemblylanguage/article.php/c12667/Thunking-in-Win32.htm) with a (very hack-y) workaround for this exact problem. It should allow you to use `SetWindowsHookEx` in the way you're currently trying to use it. However, I would recommend re-thinking the way your application is hooking and instead see if there is a way to register a single global function or static member function as your callback for your application.

Unrelated to your question: unless you've omitted code in your sample, you never unhook the hook that is set in `SetWindowsHookEx`. Take a look at the [MSDN for `UnhookWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644993(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Changed the callback to static and its member and its working now! Thank you.

Comment: Note that [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) supports generating such thunks cross-platform – even on iOS(!).  It also supports generating thunks with almost-arbitrary signatures.