# WPF capture mouse click outside of my application

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I am porting a WinForms application to WPF.  As part of the existing functionality the user can click on any running windows application (including outside of my running WPF app) that will capture the window handle and mouse coordinates.  Is this possible?

Comment: You already told us it's possible in your question :P

Comment: Unfortunately the globalhook method doesn't seem to play nice with WPF :(

Comment: I'm not sure WPF has anything to do with it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180773/setwindowshookex-for-wh-mouse  Maybe you should run the hook in its own thread though.

Comment: I have checked out that article but it is implemented in C++ using windows hooks.  I was hoping to find a native C# WPF way of achieving this as most of the returning structures are troublesome when using in C# as I found when trying to port the initial hook code from the working Winforms app

Comment: Sorry for the trouble you've had, Mark.  Maybe try to get it started though?  We SO guys are pretty good at p/invoke stuff.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do it with WinApi global Hoocker for mouse and keyboard

```
private readonly MouseHookListener m_MouseHookManager;

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     m_MouseHookManager = new MouseHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
     m_MouseHookManager.Enabled = true;
     m_MouseHookManager.MouseClick += m_mouseHookListener_Coordinates;

}

private void m_mouseHookListener_Coordinates(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(this,"Coordinate X:"+e.X +" Coordinate Y:"+e.Y,"Coordinates",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

And is working and was tested by me

Sorry this is for Windows Form App

Comment: It seems the `MouseHookListener` is from an external library (https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/documentation)