# Getting and setting cursor position before the system set the cursor position?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get and set the cursor position before the system(Windows) update the cursor position or somehow set a limit to where the cursor can move.

Tried `GetCursorPos()`, It execute too late.

Tried `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook, It slowed down the cursor movement (basically introduced massive lags), and I couldn't change the mouse position..

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to limit the cursor positioning globally(outside the application bounds) , let's say that I have an invisible 400px*400px box how can I limit the cursor to be in the box area?

Sure that I can check if it's out of bounds and then clamp the position to the box bounds, but at this point the cursor is already out of the bounds, that's why I need to check where the cursor is going to be and then clamp it before the system change it's position.

Comment: That does not answer the question. What does keeping the cursor inside that rectangle accomplish?

Comment: @Anders literally nothing, I just need the cursor to be in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ClipCursor` inside your low-level mouse hook. This is rather evil because the mouse is a shared resource.

A nice application only calls `ClipCursor` when it is the foreground application.

Answer (score 0):

`WH_MOUSE` is more effective (`WH_MOUSE_LL` may significantly slow down your computer) but hook programs must be placed in DLL.

This allows hook processes to be loaded and run in each process.

On the other hand, the `WH_MOUSE_LL` process must switch back to the original process each time to run outside the process. This is a very slow operation.

Comment: I can't test it atm so lets say that it worked and now I just need to set the cursor position, How do I do that? because `SetCursorPos()` will change the old cursor position.

Comment: @Barak A similar example：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180773/setwindowshookex-for-wh-mouse

Comment: I know how to set it up but I don't know how to then change the future position..

Comment: @Barak Is it not your intention to hook the mouse position and reset it? Why not use `SetCursorPos ()`?

Comment: @Barak In addition, as @Anders said, because cursor is a shared resource. If an application confines the cursor, it must release the cursor by using `ClipCursor` before relinquishing control to another application. The function confines the cursor to a rectangular area on the screen.